# What is the name of the fastener that looks sort of like a screw and sort of like a nail?

Tags: fastener, trailer

I am starting in on a cargo trailer conversion and the first "screw" I attempted to remove (that fastens the plywood would the metal supports) would not thread out and I stripped it.  I managed to extract it.  It had a Phillips head, but it's more like a nail.

I have seen other videos where owners have encountered these fasteners and said they are a pain to remove. But I haven't found one that identifies it by name.  Which would help in my search to identify the best way to extract these things.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's called spiral shank nail or screw nail.

Comment: yep, that's it.

Comment: I've since found it referred to as "hell" nails on a few cargo trailer conversion groups! haha!

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a concrete nail.

Not made of concrete but for use in concrete. ;)-

Comment: i agree that it looks like a hardened steel concrete nail, but the OP stated that it has a phillips socket ... i have a suspicion that it is something like a concrete nail, but meant for driving into steel ... no idea why it has a phillips socket

Comment: @jsotola correct.  Philips head.  And commonly used in cargo trailers in the US (unfortunately for me).